# WordPress: Box-shadow for featured image

Tags: css, json, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I would like to add a box-shadow to my featured image in the query block.

```
"core/post-featured-image": {
    "border": {
      "radius": "24px"
    },
    "shadow": SHADOW HERE
  }
}
```

I did this in the theme.json but got this result:

[image]

[image]

I would either need to change where the border radius appears or the box-shadow. Is this possible? I am trying to avoid using an additional .css-file for that theme here.

And one more question: Is there a list of possible attributes for a block somewhere?

Thanks in advance!